# Undefined variable: sections (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fawateer\resources\views\sections.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I just want to show data from database using `compact` method, but it seem like it doesn't work , and I don't know what is wrong.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $sections = Sections::all();
     
    return view('sections', compact('sections'));
    
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($sections as $section)
  <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>{{ $section->section_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $section->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $section->Created_by }}</td>
        <td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

route web.php

```
Route::resource('sections', 'SectionsController');
```

Comment: What does `dd($sections);` output in your method?

Comment: i used dd($sections); in return of index function and it bring all database from sections table , but still not work with passing variable from controller to view by compact method

Comment: still get this error message in output                                                                           Undefined variable: sections (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fawateer\resources\views\sections.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=>on laravel 8 use this route and import on top on route like

use App\Http\Controllers\SectionsController;

Route::resource('sections', SectionsController::class);

import top on your controller

use App\Models\Sections;

its working your fine.i can try your code its work.
```

Comment: i wrote these comands                                                                                                      
 php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:clear                                                                                                                       with changing some uri directory but still have this error message above

Comment: your code working fine i can run can say that which laravel version you can use

Comment: actually i work on laravel v*7 ,but finally i figure it out ,by changing some route lines ordering , that was the problem and it work ,thanks for replying

Comment: ok.if you help this code please up mark that ans because other people can use this code.

Answer (score 1):

in web.php route for resource write it like

```
Route::resource('sections', SectionsController::class);
```